# Optapy/Optaplanner task for complicated logistic problem

Tags: optaplanner, vehicle-routing, optapy

I'd like to ask a general question. Is there any example of OptaPy/Optaplanner package to solve a model, where several trucks (with certain capacity) distribute operation machines between customers. The operation of the machine at the customer place takes some time. Once this is done, the machine or machines are collected and moved to another customers. The key here is to keep the trucks busy, collect the machines at the customer places and minimize the traveled distance by the trucks. They all starts from some central depo.

I'm looking for some example or some direction. Any help or suggestion is very appreciated.
Thanks.

I started with the origin-destination matrix. But I'm not sure that's the right thing to start with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you seen this video?
https://youtu.be/3Bgt4xC4a1M